# how can I send data to my python code in android studio

Tags: python, kotlin, chaquopy

My Kotlin code:

```kotlin
fun get_path(): PyObject? {
    val py = getInstance()
    val pyf = py.getModule("1")
    val va = pyf.callAttr ("pdf_files", inputvalue)
    return va
}
```

My Python code

```py
def pdf_files(user_input):
    pdfFiles = []
    path = str(user_input)
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
            pdfFiles.append("/" + filename)
    return path, pdfFiles
```

Comment: Please edit your question to give details of your actual problem. For example, if you got an error message, post its text.

Comment: I want to give a folder name(user_input) to my python code so I can get access to that folder using python.

Comment: It looks like you're already doing that. So what's the problem?